# No Claims Discount

Tags: united-kingdom, car-insurance

In the UK, if I am involved in an accident that is not my fault will I lose my No Claims Discount?

If the No Claims Discount is protected, can I still move to another insurer?

Comment: Not yet voted to close, but seems very specific to a specific insurance company policy at a single point in time, not a generally useful question.

Comment: feel free to VTC, but I meant it as a general question on area of insurance I find confusing and not well documented.

Comment: @sdg: No claims discount is a general thing in the UK that cuts across all insurers and has been around for many years. Whilst there may not be one answer that applies exactly to every single insurance company, it will be possible to give a broad overview.

Comment: Just to clarify: No Claims Discounts typically are precisely that: discounts you get for not making claims. It doesn't matter why you didn't, whether that was because you didn't have an accident, because you paid out of your own pocket, or whether someone else paid for your damages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about the UK (however it should be the same), but in Australia if the accident is not your fault and you are able to prove this (i.e. signed statement from other party, police report, independent witnesses) you should not lose your NCD. You should double check this with your insurer.

If your NCD is protected with your current insurer then even if you are at fault in an accident you should not lose your level of NCD. If you move to another insurer it would depend on the new insurer whether you retain your NCD protection, and it is something you need to check and/or negotiate with them.